# Add multiple buttons with different functionalities in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a tkinter window with `Select file` button to apply `DataCheck` function to excel files one by one with the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from data_check import DataCheck

def on_quit():
    if messagebox.askokcancel('Confirmation', 'Do you really want to quit?'):
        root.destroy()

def open_file():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(('Excel Files', '.xlsx'),))
    if file:
        DataCheck(file)

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Select file', command=open_file)
btn.pack()

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_quit)
root.mainloop()
```

Let's say I want to add **another button** with the following function to open folders, how could I do that with tkinter? Many thanks.

```
def open_directory():
    directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith('.xlsx') or filename.endswith('.xls'):
            fuullname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            if fullname:
                DataCheck(fullname)
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text = 'Select folder', command = open_directory)
```

Code for reference:

```
root = Tk()
dict_words = {1: "open_file",
            2: "open_directory"
             }
for k, j in dict_words.items():
    b = Button(root, width=20, text=j, padx=5, pady=5)
    b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the text of the buttons as keys and the function references as the values of the dictionary `dict_func` as below:

```py
dict_func = {"Open File": open_file,
             "Open Directory": open_directory}
```

Then create the buttons using the dict as below:

```py
for name, func in dict_func.items():
    tk.Button(root, width=20, text=name, padx=5, pady=5, command=func).pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, but there is one problem: after I selecting and execting one file, it automaticlly open folder.

```
import tkinter as tk
from data_check import DataCheck
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
import os

def on_quit():
    if messagebox.askokcancel('Confirmation', 'Do you really want to quit?'):
        root.destroy()
def open_file():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [('Excel files', '.xlsx .xls .csv')])
    if file:
        DataCheck(file)
        
def open_directory():
    directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xls"):
            fullname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            if fullname:
                DataCheck(fullname)

root = tk.Tk()

dict_func = {1: 'open_file',
             2: 'open_directory'
        }
for k, j in dict_func.items():
    b = tk.Button(root, width = 20, text = j, padx = 5, pady = 5, command = lambda: [open_file(), open_directory()])
    b.pack()

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_quit)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command = lambda: [open_file(), open_directory()]` will call `open_file()` and then `open_directory()`.  So what you said problem is expected result.